# How would it be possible to remove extra comma at the end of a string in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
public Image addComments(String createComments) {
    comments.append(createComments + ",");
    return this;
}
```

This is what I get, A,B,

This is how I want it to be: A,B

I tried  using a regular expression
`createComments = createComments.replaceAll(",$", "");`
But It didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There is not enough information for us to answer.

Comment: You would need to use the regular expression on `comments`, not `createComments`. Or if there is some collection these comments are coming from you could join them with `String::join` or `Collectors::joining` instead and avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: i would suggest to use a List<String> instead of a StringBuilder. Then you can use `String.join`.

Comment: In any case, *you* added it, so rather than thinking about how to remove the thing you added, think about how to not add what you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `comments` is a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) you can avoid adding a trailing comma:

```
public Image addComments(String createComments) {
    if (comments.length() > 0) comments.append(",");
    comments.append(createComments);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can avoid this whole comma situation with use of any Collection and String.join

```
Collection<String> comments = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");

final String joinedComments = String.join(",", comments);

System.out.println(joinedComments);
```

This will return

```
A,B,C,D
```

Comment: This answer is doesn't completely solves the problem that OP has asked.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt, you're right. I just tried to offer another approach.